# How to prevent I/O hiccup caused by single process?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, io

I'm looking for a way to prevent single process from slowing whole desktop system (ubuntu 11) by massive disk I/O. Is there any tool that would allow to limit disk operations rate per process or even better to put such limit on process that do massive I/O longer that predefined period?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48152/9851).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice). You can use it to change I/O scheduling class and priority.